# Access Company Directory on Samsung S3

Tags: contacts, exchange, samsung-galaxy-s-3

Does anyone know how to access Microsoft Exchange company directory on Samsung S3?  This used to be available on my previous phone (HTC Desire) but I can't seem to find it on the Samsung S3.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have the Exchange account added on your phone, if you go to Contacts, and search for a name, it should bring up directory results. Make sure you hit the search or enter button on the keyboard.